# Converting a cpp code to an appropriate assembly language for the 8085 simulator

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, microprocessors, 8085

I wrote a cpp code for applying Newton Raphson method for a polynomical function (ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx^3 + ex^3 + fx^2 + gx + h) (I assumed all variables were 1, so I just defined a) and I want to convert it for 8085 simulator, could you help me? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define EPSILON 0.001
using namespace std;

double func(double x)
{
    int a=1;
    return a*x*x*x*x*x*x+a*x*x*x*x*x+a*x*x*x*x+a*x*x*x+a*x*x*x+a*x*x+a*x+a;
}

double derivFunc(double x)
{
    int a=1;
    return 6*a*x*x*x*x*x+5*a*x*x*x*x+4*a*x*x*x+3*a*x*x+3*a*x*x+2*a*x+a;
}

void newtonRaphson(double x)
{
    double h = func(x) / derivFunc(x);
    while (abs(h) >= EPSILON)
    {
        h = func(x)/derivFunc(x);

        x = x - h;
    }
    cout << "The value of the root is : " << x;
}

int main()
{
    double x0 = 10;
    newtonRaphson(x0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get an 8085 software floating point library; 8085 doesn't have an FPU.  Or convert your code to fixed-point, or write your own soft-FP library if you know floating point very well.  Implementing the logic is straightforward, but doing any floating point operation (except absolute value) is non-trivial on an ISA without an FPU.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I don't know floating point well. So how about 8086? Is it also same or do I have a chance to convert it easily?

Comment: If your 8086 emulator has an 8087 FPU, there are C++ compilers that can make code for it.  e.g. I `bcc` targets 16-bit x86, and might support FP instructions.